# How to completely restore saved <div> tag in localstorage using javascript?

Tags: javascript, local-storage, web-storage

I have a problem in restoring the  tag after saving it locally  in localstorage using javascript

here is my code saving the div tag in localstorage

```
function saveqform() {
    var parent = document.getElementById("questions");
    console.log(parent);
    if (parent === undefined) {
        return;
    } else {
        localStorage.qtag = parent;
    }
}
```

here is my code restoring the div tag back from localstorage

```
function reloadqform() {
    console.log(localStorage.qid);
    console.log(localStorage.qtag);
    if (localStorage.qid === undefined || localStorage.qtag === undefined) {
        return;
    } else {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var saved = localStorage.qtag;
            var parent = document.getElementById("element");
            parent.appendChild(saved);
        });
    }
}
```

unfortunately the above code only outputs undefined when recovering the div tag from local storage, so I followed another approach by saving the innerhtml instead of the whole tag
here is my code to save the inner html

```
function saveqform() {
        var parent = document.getElementById("questions");
        console.log(parent);
        if (parent === undefined) {
            return;
        } else {
            localStorage.qtag = parent.innerHTML;
        }
    }
```

here is my code to recover the tag

```
 function reloadqform() {
        console.log(localStorage.qid);
        console.log(localStorage.qtag);
        if (localStorage.qid === undefined || localStorage.qtag === undefined) {
            return;
        } else {
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var saved = localStorage.qtag;
                var parent = document.getElementById("element");
                parent.innerHTML=saved;
            });
        }
    }
```

actually this code restores the div tag and the elements inside the tag perfectly except that I lost all of the onclick functions I already set using .onclick method in javascript
so what can I do to simply restore the tag completely including all of its actions thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can't store a DOM reference in local storage.  Local storage stores strings only, not DOM references.

You can store the contents of a DIV, but not the DIV object itself.  If you want to have event handlers on the restored object, then you will have to reattach the event handlers after you create the restored object.

In your second example, if you are rewriting all the innerHTML of the parent, the it will destroy and recreate all child elements and that will destroy all event handlers that may have already been set.  It would be better to just save/restore the individual state of one particular element and thus just set the `.innerHTML` on one element that has no child elements.  Done this way, you won't destroy any event handlers.

Cookies or local storage can store state from one page to the next as strings.

One thing to keep in mind here is that DOM objects live ONLY for the lifetime of the current document in the current page.  Once a new page is loaded, EVERYTHING that was part of that first page is destroyed and a whole new document and whole new set of DOM objects and a whole new javascript environment is created.

Comment: it's strange because he saying that it's working well the div restore.
but only the events gone. So is it saving dom elements?

Comment: @Dvir - yes, that's because in his second example he is storing `.innerHTML` which is a string and then he is assigning that innerHTML to the new page.  That should work.  Event handlers will have to be manually reattached in the new document.  You can't save an event handler in local storage.

Comment: OK, what's the alternative I mean now I have no way but to reassign the event handlers again, is there a way to just do this in one step, I mean storing the whole dom, or shall I continue with my approach

Comment: @A'amerMohamed - you probably need to store contents of nodes only, not whole blocks of HTML, but we'd need to see the HTML in the area of interest and what actually needs to be stored (likely there's no reason to actually store HTML, just contents of certain objects).  Event handlers are lost when you "reconstitute" the HTML by assigning `.innerHTML` with embedded objects in that HTML.  Event handlers on not lost if you just set the `.innerHTML` of one node and there are no child nodes in that `.innerHTML`.  No, you cannot store the whole DOM, event handlers and all.

Comment: just to fulfill your curiosity what I am doing is dynamically generating questions like google forms style, but I need when I refresh the page , the user doesn't lose all his changes, that's why I need the whole HTML block to be save for simplicity but I guess now, that the data was saved and the structure was rebuilt, any way Thanks

Comment: @A'amerMohamed - Then, you should save each question individually (without the corresponding HTML) and then reconstruct each individual question object with event handlers when the page is reloaded.